# How to run multiple inputs in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using jupyter to test my code, and basically my code asks for while 0 is < than 10

The thing is, after each input, the code does something to that input and then, after finishing, it asks me for the next input. Is there a way to just paste the 10 inputs instantly and let the code run them? It takes me way too much time to copy and paste each input 1 by 1.

If there is a way, please be detailed as I am new to jupyter and programming

Comment: can you add source code example to understand your query easily?

Answer (score 0):

You may make some hacker to make this, paste the hacker at the beginning of your code, then you can directly run it in jupyter notebook with `Alt+Enter`, no `input text box` will be shown in jupyter again to let you input `"Hello"` & `"World"`.

**NOTE:** This just for you to test your other code logic quickly, not for product run, something like a test mock.

**test.py:**

```
# start hacker
f = open('a.txt', 'w')
f.write('"Hello"')
f.write('\n')
f.write('"World"')
f.write('\n')
f.close()
file = open("a.txt")
input = file.readline
# end hacker

for i in range(2):
    val = input()
    print('my name: ' + val)
```

**output:**

> my name: "Hello"
>
> my name: "World"

Above hacker make you automatically read `"Hello"` & `"World"` during the iteration.